# Puppeteer System requirements

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I put a script into production today and dropped my API, I believe I will have to use a separate server.
So, what server configuration should I use for 1000 requests / hour?

**Steps to reproduce**
Set up a cheaper machine on digitalOcean and ran 5 times at the same time.

**My server:**

- Puppeteer version: last
- Platform / OS version: Ubuntu 16
- Node.js version: 10

**The code I was running**

```js
async function getContent(url) {
  console.log("getContent")
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args:[`--window-size=${1800},${1200}`, '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});

  var times = 1;
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(times++)
    if (times > 10) clearInterval(timer);
  }, 1000);

  await page.waitFor(10000)
  return await page.content();
}

async function searchdata(content, url) {
  console.log("searchdata")
  const $ = cheerio.load(content);

  let imoveis = [];
  let paginas;
  let quantidadeEncontrada = $(".js-title .js-total-records").text().trim()

  if(quantidadeEncontrada<7){
    return{
      result:false,
      message:"Não encontramos um número de amostras maiores do que 8",
      quantidadeEncontrada:quantidadeEncontrada,
      link:url
    };
  }

  //Não pode ser arrow function porque perdemos o this do elemento :D
  $(".results-list > div").each(function () {
    if(imoveis.length<quantidadeEncontrada){
      // let area = $(this).find(".property-card__container .property-card__details .property-card__detail-area .property-card__detail-value").text();
      let valorVenda = $(this).find(".property-card__values .property-card__price").text();
      let link = $(this).find(".property-card__header a").attr("href");
      valorVenda = valorVenda.replace("R$", "").trim().replace(/\./g, "");
      if(valorVenda.trim()*1){
        imoveis.push({
          valorVenda: parseInt(valorVenda.trim()),
          link: "https://www.vivareal.com.br" + link
        });
      }
      // paginas = $(".pagination__wrapper li[data-type]").length
    }
  });

  return {
    result: true,
    imoveis: imoveis,
    amostrasQuantidade:imoveis.length,
    paginas: paginas,
    quantidadeEncontrada:quantidadeEncontrada * 1,
    url:url
  }
}
```

I also created an Issue on puppeteer's repo: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i can't find any information on the web.

I decided to use it on Google Cloud Functions, with 2G of RAM

Comment: Are you happy with your decision?

Comment: No! Have you any suggestion?

Comment: I am running my puppeteer on Windows VPS, 32GB RAM but only 4 core. I need better CPU to run more threads... so I am also looking :)

Comment: Belhor, Omg! this is a sniper to kill my ant, hehe.
I'm using Cloud Functions and my budget for 5k requests is R$0,00, 'cause my function runs fast and small, so i think it's the better to me.

http://prntscr.com/u55djj

Comment: Maybe it is time for me to move from VPS to cloud and just scale it up as needed. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Google Cloud need min of 2GB, i've tested it repeatedly, other providers don't need 2GB, google cloud seems like weaker therefore wont run below 2GB. Kinda regret moving over to google cloud but in terms of functions, GC is better, replacement / updating of instances.

Comment: @CodeGuru wich server you use?